# Blocking countries IP to access laravel

Tags: laravel

How can i limit my website visitors to only one country in laravel?

## logic

Only one country users (ip's) can visit my website rest of the world can't.

## Question

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this package: [GeoIp](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip/blob/master/README.md)

I suggest you could write your logic using the package inside a middleware, and wrap all your routes with it.

Comment: Good look! And please, if it has solved your question, mark the answer as valid  @mafortis

Comment: I'm still looking for others answer, if no luck with that i'll accept yours, please be patient.